# Artifacts and compiled .class files don't work after adding external libraries in Intelij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to use VTD-XML in my app. So I added it. But after making artifact, the latter doesn't want to work. I tried to launch class file from `out/production` directory. That's what I received:[image][image]

With disabled JIT:
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the stack, the class `IndexWriteException` is missing.  Is that a library you control?  Is it being included in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, it's that library. Strange is that this code works if I launch it in IDE, but in case of launching JAR or .class file it gives this exception.

Comment: No, thats really not all that strange at all, most IDEs will manage your classpath for you when you add libraries and such. This needs to be done manually when you run it from the command line :)

Comment: @JustDanyul I added Class-Path to manifest: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: vtd-xml.jar
Main-Class: Librarian`. All JARs are in the same directory, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: just to check, are you actually running a executable jar now? As in "java -jar yourjarname.jar". In the example in your original post you where not running the jar (so it wont pick up the manifest)

Comment: @JustDanyul I've tried two ways: to run JAR and to launch .class file. The results are identical.